# How to show the current instead of "multiple" git branch in visual studio 17.4.4 status bar (multiple repos)

Tags: git, branch, visual-studio-2022, multiple-repositories

Since the new installation of Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - LTSC 17.4
Version 17.4.4 the status bar in the right lower corner is showing be "multiple" for the branch name instead of the current branch.

[image]

I use a solution which has a subrepository. When I start VisualStudio and choose the correct repository in the status bar it shows me the folder view in the solution explorer and actually shows the correct branch name. But as soon as I load the solution it switches to the uninformative display as I have posted.

I looked inside the source control settings, searched around the net and read [Multi-repository Support Released](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/multi-repository-support-released/) and the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-multi-repository-support?view=vs-2022), but they show basically how to use all git operations in the context of multiple repositories and I could not find the information on how to make VisualStudio show the current checked out branch in the status bar.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to turn off multi-repository support in the options under Environment>Preview Features.

However, if you need this enabled for your workflow, then maybe someone else can offer you more info as I am not sure how to have branch shown while that is enabled.

Comment: perfect, this helps a lot. I don't use the source control system of Visual Studio to manage my repositories, I only need the display for brief orientation.

Comment: It seems like we cannot turn off multirepo support anymore - no such option in Preview Featuters menu and nowhere else (in VS 2022 v.17.8.3). Accordind to MS video it seems like your branches have to have the same name in different repos to show it in the status bar (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2021/08/Git-Part3-MultiRepo_Support.mp4).